# How to use local Service instance to call methods outside of onServiceConnected() that are declared in ILocalService.java interface

Tags: android, interface, service

Regarding [Local Service Sample](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#LocalServiceSample) I have succeeded in defining methods declared in my ILocalService.java, but I don't know how to call these methods outside of an activity's onServiceConnected(). I can call only them from within onServiceConnected() which does not seem to be of much use. Am I limited to that? Here is my ILocalService.java:

```
/**************************************************************************************************
 * Filename: ILocalService.java
 * Project name: Local Service Sample
 * Application name: Local Service
 * Description: This file contains an example interface for LocalService
 **************************************************************************************************/

package com.marie.localservicesample;

public interface ILocalService {

    public LocalService getService();

    public int getStatusCode();
}
```

My assumption is that I should be able to call methods declared in my ILocalService.java. These calls should not be limited to from **within** onServiceConnected() by an activity that is bound to my LocalService.java. How would I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you will use the service reference outside the serviceConnected method. Mostly it will throw nullpointerexception.

Make a button in your activity and try to use service reference in its onClick.
Click the button at least waiting 10 seconds. It will work fine.

This indicates that service takes time to bind to the local reference variable.
ServiceConnected method is only used to tell that service got connected and now it is usable.

In order to use properly service outside the serviceConnected method.
You can maintain a boolean flag in the serviceConnected method.

On the basis of flag value use service anywhere you want

This is as far as i know.

Hope it helps :)

Comment: thanks for the answer. I may have do that. But I think I found a solution that works for me for now.

Comment: great then :). If you found a better answer do post that also. so others can also get the benefit

Comment: @Javantor it won't let me post an answer to my own question for like 8 hours. But here's what I found: If I declare mBoundService as "private ILocalService mBoundService = null;" Then in onServiceConnected() assign it as follows: "mBoundService = (ILocalService) service;" Then I get a Service instance that allows me to call any method declared in my ILocalService.java from anywhere in the activity bound to the local Service. But I think your answer is good so I will accept it and vote it up. If you liked my question may I ask you to vote if up?

Comment: sure. It was a good question. as i faced the same when i used services for the first time